# Pre-filter JS PIVOT TABLE fields

Tags: javascript, pivot-table, pivottable.js

Below is my script to generate pivot table:

```
var derivers = $.pivotUtilities.derivers;
var renderers = $.extend($.pivotUtilities.renderers, $.pivotUtilities.c3_renderers);
$('#output').pivotUI(
    [{
        Line: 'X',
        Party: 'AB'
    }, {
        Line: 'X',
        Party: 'CD'
    }, {
        Line: 'Y',
        Party: 'EF'
    }, {
        Line: 'Y',
        Party: 'AB'
    }, {
        Line: 'X',
        Party: 'GH'
    }, {
        Line: 'Y',
        Party: 'IJ'
    }, {
        Line: 'X',
        Party: 'AB'
    }], {
        renderers: renderers,
        rows: ['Line'],
        cols: ['Party']
    });
```

I would like to pre filter Party column with only 'AB' on load. User can select all items if he would like to. But on loading pivot table, I would lilke pre filter Party column.
Could you please tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use inclusions/exclusions as options for the pivot function. These take an object as input with key being the column name and value being an array of your filtered attributes.

Here is a link to JSfiddle for the same:-

https://jsfiddle.net/ab3kwcnp/1/

```
$('#output').pivotUI([
    {country: "USA", city: "Boston"},
    {country: "USA", city: "NYC"},
    {country: "UK", city: "London"},
],
{
    rows: ["country"],
    cols: ["city"],
    inclusions: {country:["USA"]}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `inclusions` or `exclusions` parameters: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters